# Why GCC generates a mov of the array's beginning on every loop iteration to access array using []? (-O3, x86)

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86

### Description

I created a sample to study the TLB access/misses statistics. Sample writes `1` to every 4096-th element of the array. Array has `10'000 * 4096` bytes. I expect to see `10'000` TLB stores only, but generated assembly loads beginning of the array every iteration, resulting in `10'000` TLB loads in addition to stores. `-O3` optimization is applied

When I looked into the assembly, I noticed that the for-loop looks like that:

1. move beginning of the array to the register
2. set to 1 a shifted beginning of the array
3. increase index
4. jump to **step 1**

**Question**: Why step 1 is executed every single iteration? Beginning of the array is not changing. I expect the beginning to be loaded once and the jump to be to **step 2**

### C code

(main just calls this `test_function` 10K times):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define REPEAT 10000
#define PAGESIZE 4096
#define PAGES 10000

char *data = NULL;

inline void test_function()
{
    for (int i = 0; (i < PAGES * PAGESIZE); i += (PAGESIZE)) {
        data[i] = 1;
    }
}


int main()
{
    data = (char *) malloc(PAGES * PAGESIZE);
    for (int idx = 0; idx < REPEAT; idx++)
        test_function();
    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

### Generated assembly with gcc and -O3

```
    1090:       mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rip+0x2f81]        # 4018 <data>
    1097:       mov    BYTE PTR [rdx+rax*1],0x1
    109b:       add    rax,0x1000
    10a1:       cmp    rax,0x2710000
    10a7:       jne    1090 <main+0x30>
```

### perf stats for 100'000 repetitions

Per function call we can see:

- **10K L1 cache loads**, 10K L1 cache stores
- **10K TLB loads**, 10K TLB stores
- **~0 TLB load misses**, 10K TLB store misses
  So load of the array's beginning is always cached in TLB, but it's still accessed. **Why?**

```
1002500646      L1-dcache-load:u          (66.50%)
 998346580      L1-dcache-stores:u        (66.68%)
 995750153      dTLB-loads:u              (66.81%)
 998020884      dTLB-stores:u             (66.74%)
     34586      dTLB-loads-misses:u       (66.68%)
1003649391      dTLB-stores-misses:u      (66.58%)
```

### Platform

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10610U CPU

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0

Compilation line: `g++ ./tlb.cpp -O3 -g -o gcc.out`

Comment: Note that your C code does not compile: non-constant initialisers are not supported in C.

Comment: `add    rax,0xa000` Very strange to see RAX raised by 40960 instead of 4096.

Comment: @SepRoland, thanks for noticing. Sorry for confusion, I did several step experiments, including with (PAGESIZE * 10). I updated the question with 0x1000 value, which is 4096, to align with explanation

Comment: @fuz, thanks for noticing - you were right. I adjusted the code in the question. For some reason, my local GCC allowed it easily. Maybe because it's WSL-based setup and GCC there is different from the upstream.

Comment: @RostislavPovelikin It is allowed in C++.  Make sure you do not confuse these two!  If you compile with a C++ compiler, you are writing C++ code.  Even if they look similar, the semantics are far from being the same.  Do not use a C++ compiler to compile C code and vice versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code does not know what `data` holds when the code runs.  Therefore, it is conceivable that `data[i]` overlays `data`:

```
data = (char *)&data;
```

when this happens, assigning to `data[i]` could modify `data` itself.  Thus the compiler cannot simply assume they do not alias and must reload `data` after each access.  Granted, with some more code it could fix this, but the compiler writers have not implemented that.

To avoid this problem, make sure to cache global variables in local variables if this sort of problem could occur:

```
inline void test_function()
{
    char *d;

    d  = data;
    for (int i = 0; (i < PAGES * PAGESIZE); i += (PAGESIZE)) {
        d[i] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think we can also mention that we get the same [good] effect if `data` is passed in as a function parameter.

Comment: Also, this is because a `char *` can alias _any_ type (even itself). If we change to `short *data;` the compiler does _not_ reload the pointer because a `short *` can _not_ alias a `short *` pointer (i.e. itself).

Comment: @CraigEstey, thanks for your comments! Can you please clarify what do you mean under term "alias" in a context of C? Do you mean that because `char *` is a common way to read any memory, compiler almost treats it as `void *`? While when it's something more specific - compiler treats it as a properly typed pointer, thus it can't change the value of the pointer itself?

Comment: @RostislavPovelikin You can use pointers of type `char *` to point to objects of any type, same as `void *` pointers.  This is an exception to the *strict aliasing rule* which states that you can only access an object through a pointer of correct type.  Two pointers *alias* if the objects they point to overlap.  If two pointers could alias, a write through one pointer could affect the value read by dereferencing the other, so the compiler cannot cache the value of the other pointers pointee while writing through the first one.

Comment: @CraigEstey: Yes, function parameters are private to the function and only come into existence as copies of the arguments, so it's impossible for one to be pointing to itself.  The lifetime of the parameter hadn't started when the caller's args are read, so it would be wild pointer UB if it passed a pointer that happened to be pointing to the stack space that will end up holding the parameter in the callee.

Comment: @fuz, thanks for explanation. C11, draft N1570 has no term "aliasing" as the way you used and other discussions are using - Section 6.5 paragraph 7 literally states what you said, but never calls it as "aliasing". Do you know where this term was actually defined or appeared first?

Comment: @RostislavPovelikin Please post a separate question about this.  Comments are not for extended discussion and we are already veering off topic.

Comment: @RostislavPovelikin Essentially correct.  _Alias_ can be read as _points to_ or _overlaps_. C didn't get `void *` until the 1990s, so `char *` was used in many places where we'd use `void *` today. The `char *` [aliasing] exception allows: `char *data = (char *) data;` to be valid/useful (not UB) and the compiler must allow for this. Storing via `data` can modify what `data` points to, so it must refetch. But, with any other type (`short *data;`), the compiler assumes it can do `short *d = data; for (int i = 0; i < ...; i += ...) d[i] = 1;` because `short *data = (short *) data;` is UB.

Comment: @RostislavPovelikin Putting a global pointer variable into a function scoped var is good practice. For old compilers that had _no_ optimizer, we would _have_ to do it ourselves: `short *data_with_a_very_long_name; int func() { register short *d = data_with_a_very_long_name; for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) d[i] = 1; return 0; }` Without the extra temp var, some compilers would generate the "dumb" code of refetching `data_with_a_very_long_name` on every iteration.