# Efficiency of working with reference vs a local variable in C

Tags: c, linux, pointers, memory

I have defined a function in C as follows:

```
char **fun(size_t *size) {  
  size_t local_size = 0;
  while (...) {
    //Function code...
    local_size++;
  }
  *size = local_size;
  //Code for returning
}
```

As you can see, it has a local variable that serves as a counter and then returns it by setting the value of the size reference to the value of local size.

Also, I implemented the function by working directly with the value pointed by the input reference, like so:

```
char **fun(size_t *size) {  
  *size = 0;
  while (...) {
    //Function code...
    (*size)++;
  }
  //Code for returning
}
```

Given they have the same behavior, which option is more efficient if I know there will be many accesses to the variable inside the function? Is it faster to work with the local variable option to take advantage of stack memory allocation?

Comment: The first example is what I always do in a similar situation. `local_size` could live in a CPU register and would be fast. In the 2nd example, we're forcing a memory write each time the value changes. With the first example, we only write that memory _once_.

Comment: It's likely that the optimizer will realize that `*size` can be cached in a register, so both versions will produce the same code. @CraigEstey

Comment: @barmar I´m using the `-O3` flag in the gcc compiler, does it guarantee that the compiler will automatically cache `*size`?

Comment: It depends on whether you call other functions in the loop. If you do, it can't be sure that those functions don't reference `*size`, so it has to assign to the variable.

Comment: Maybe declaring `size_t *restrict size` will preclude that.

Comment: @Barmar There's more detail on this from this recent question: [Why GCC generates a mov of the array's beginning on every loop iteration to access array using \[\]? \(-O3, x86)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78017239/5382650) I prefer to _not_ assume the optimizer will "do the right thing" for such things. To me, using `local_size` is a better/clearer option, for performance, and clarity of code/intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `//Function code...` contains anything that might access what `size` points to, the compiler cannot optimize by caching a copy of `*size`:

- If it uses a file-scope identifier for an object that may be aliased with a `size_t`, `size` might point to that object.
- If it calls any other function the compiler cannot see or know the definition of, that function might access `*size`.
- If it obtains a character pointer from somewhere not fully known to the compiler and uses that character pointer to modify memory, that might change `*size`, because character types are allowed to access any objects.
- Your example function has no other parameters, but real-world functions often have multiple parameters, which raise the same issues, that they might point to the same object `size` points to.

So, you are better off with the first version of the function.

Comment: Would the `restrict` qualifier tell the compiler that none of this aliasing can happen? Or does it only address the last point?

Comment: `restrict` would address some of those, right?

Comment: @Barmar: Re “Would the `restrict` qualifier tell the compiler that none of this aliasing can happen?”: Yes, but is that what you want to tell the compiler? In OP’s simple example, maybe yes. But suppose something else does write to `*size` during the routine, but you do not care and just want to stick the final count there when the routine is done, even if some subroutine used it for temporary storage in the meantime. Caching it yourself and storing at the end accomplishes that. In contrast, adding `restrict` makes the program behavior undefined. In cases where there are other parameters,…

Comment: … there can be other interactions to consider. So the answer to this question is not simply to add `restrict`. It is plenty easy to keep a local counter, store it at the end, and keep the code simple and clear.

Comment: If other code needs to use the incremental values of `size`, you can't cache it into a local variable in the first place. So any time you can use the local variable, it also makes sense to use `restrict`.

Comment: @Barmar: I did not say the other code needs to use the incremental values of `size`. I said, as an example, some other code writes to `size` in the meantime and you do not care.

Comment: Well, that would be perverse. This seems to be an output parameter of this function, no one else should be modifying it while the function is running. You can make up theoretical code, but practical code should never have such screw cases.

Comment: @Barmar: Re “… practical code should never have such screw cases”: ROTFL.

Comment: Perhaps, but I was serious. If that output location is being modified from some other code at the same time, you have a bug. The two versions of the code *should* be equivalent except for optimization.

Comment: @Barmar This is a simple example. In the more general case, would you be advocating `void func(struct foo **dptr) { *dptr = malloc(sizeof(struct foo)); (*dptr)->x = 3; (*dptr)->y = 4; (*dptr)->z = 5; }` instead of: `void func(struct foo **dptr) { struct foo *sptr = malloc(sizeof(struct foo)); sptr->x = 3; sptr->y = 4; sptr->z = 5; *dptr = sptr; }`

Comment: @CraigEstey I'm suggesting `void func(struct foo** restrict dptr)` along with your first body.

Comment: @Barmar So, are you saying that you want the function to do: `(*dptr)->x` et. al. instead of `sptr->x` _throughout_ the function??? The former is ugly. With a slightly different signature: `struct foo *func(void)`, using `sptr` would be obvious. The use of `(*dptr)->x` serves no runtime purpose _unless_ `dptr` is being modified by another thread and you _want_ that behavior (which you said you _didn't_). You're saying that `*dptr` would be optimized, so hope for that ...

Comment: @CraigEstey I viewed this question as asking about performance, not coding style. In general I'm a proponent of caching expressions in variables just to avoid repeating complex expressions. But `local_size` is actually longer than `(*size)`.

Comment: @Barmar ... When I examine code that has `*dptr` used everywhere within the function, I have to wonder: _Did the original programmer **want** another thread to modify it?_ So, I'm having to look at lots of code to ensure that the behavior that _you_ don't want (race conditions, etc.) is not being used. With the `sptr` approach, the intent is clear: no side effects wanted.

Comment: @Barmar I _know_ you're a better programmer, so I was confused by what seemed like "temporary insanity" :-). Personally, I would have renamed the variables `local_size --> size` and `size --> size_return` so the local variable is shorter than the parameter or a global. Also, for debug (with `-g` and `-O0`), using `sptr`, the compiler [probably] generates better. The debug mode and production mode are closer (speedwise), so (maybe) less of the "my code works at `-O0` but not `-O2`"

Answer (score 1):

From an optimization perspective, it's often a good idea too make local copies of small memory objects as they can help the compiler with aliasing issues.

The compiler will naturally try to avoid memory accesses as much as possible by caching things in registers, but sometimes it's hard for the compiler to decide when to invalidate those cached values so it has to conservatively flush/reload.
(Some of this can be helped with by leaning on strict aliasing or the `restrict` qualifier, but local variables can typically do the same job).

Writing to memory locations also means that even if the compiler manages to use registers to cache those writes, it might end up forced to flush the cache sooner than if you were caching manually via a local variable, e.g., an opaque function call or an access to memory with unclear aliasing will force such a flush.

When in doubt, compare assembly outputs.